# Converting String to Integer. Why this error? I want to change the ID (string) to IC (integer). Both are arrays. I'm still a beginner by the way

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings, atoi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string ID[]={"620301025123"}; //ID array

   long long int IC[10]={0}; //IC array

   // loop to change the ID string to Array IC. I will want to increase the size 
   // of ID array, later on, to put in new data but for now, I'm just using one data
   // which is "620301025123" first.

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
     IC[i]= {atoll(ID[i].c_str())};
   }
 }
```

The error I got is:

> 14 29  C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Assign1\Untitled3.cpp [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11*/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: 1) Are you compiling with C++11 support enabled, as the error suggests? 2) Such a `for` loop, with `ID[i].c_str()`invokes undefined behavior, due to going out of bounds of array `ID`, since it contains exactly one element. 3) Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of coding randomly.

Comment: Why you used `c_str()`  ?

Comment: I expect this:  `IC[i]= {atoll(ID[i])};`

Comment: Beware: `string ID[] = { "620301025123" };` declares an array of `string` containing exactly one string (`"620301025123"`). Therefore `ID[1]` is incorrect and will lead to _undefined behaviour_ (google that term). Please tell us what you expect `IC` to contain after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: it's `#include <cstdlib>` in C++.

Then, your problem does not seem to be the conversion to `long long`, but the initialization of the string, at least that's what the warning (not an error) says. You are using extended initializer lists, which are C++11, but haven't activated C++11 support.

The warning tells you how to activate it.

And finally: Don't get in the habit of using `using namespace`, at least not globally. You can use `using` on specific symbols, but even this I'd only do locally, and never globally.

Comment: There are most likely more problems, see my comment to the question above.